# Login error with the below piece of code

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Login error with the below piece of code:

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\Users\Rocket\Downloads\setups\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");                    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']")).sendKeys("anoop8@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='identifierNext']/div[2]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys("Ihate");
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting? Please elaborate

Comment: @AnoopBhargava Can you consider the following points as: 1. Format your code properly for proper analysis. 2. Provide relevant HTML DOM. 3. Work on the Answers suggested by SO volunteers. 4. Update your current code & error stack trace within the Question area. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The path you have given for driver in

> System.setProperty(" "," ") should have double slashes as Java takes the single slash as escape character in strings. It should be
>    [image]

Comment: Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\Rocket\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.LfOKuZR3HcxN, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0},

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

While you specify `System.setProperty` you have to mention the absolute path of the geckodriver either by -

- Escaping the backslashes as :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe");
  ```

  or
- Using the forward slashes as :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/your_directory/geckodriver.exe");
  ```

  Let me know if this answers your Question.

Comment: my test is running and is detecting gecko driver but when it is moving to password it is not entering and giving an error of capabilities something like this :Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\Rocket\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.LfOKuZR3HcxN, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0},

Comment: @AnoopBhargava Can you update me your Selenium, geckodriver & Mozilla Firefox version please? Thanks

Comment: geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64 ; selenium-java-3.4.0;  firefox 53.0.3

Comment: Can you please update your current code block & the error stacktrace in the question area? Thanks

Comment: the password line where password is to be entered is not working.